# Python decorator in class

Tags: python, multithreading, locking, decorator

I want to make decorator with class variables.
How can I make decorator to class function?
Because I have a lot of functions that need to lock.
I don't want to write down

```
with self.lock: or self.lock.release()
```

every function.
this is my code!

```
class Something:
    self.lock = Lock( .. )

    #decorator
    def _lock(self, func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            self.lock.acquire()
            func(*args, **kwargs)
            self.lock.release()
        return wrapper

    @_lock
    def some_func(self,):
        #do something
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to do it like this.  It would only work for instance methods, not functions.

```
class Something:
    self.lock = Lock( .. )

    #decorator
    def _lock(func):
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.lock.acquire()
            r = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
            self.lock.release()
            return r
        return wrapper

    @_lock
    def some_func(self):
        #do something
```

Answer (score 2):

Strongly recommend that if you want a way of using a decorator to make thread locking easier, go use the `synchronised` decorator from the `wrapt` package.

For details on the design and rational for it, read the following. There is way too much detail in posts to repeat here.

- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2014/01/the-missing-synchronized-decorator.html
- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2014/01/the-synchronized-decorator-as-context.html
- http://wrapt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html

What it allows though is:

```
@synchronized # lock bound to function1
def function1():
    pass

@synchronized # lock bound to function2
def function2():
    pass

@synchronized # lock bound to Class
class Class(object):

    @synchronized # lock bound to instance of Class
    def function_im(self):
        pass

    @synchronized # lock bound to Class
    @classmethod
    def function_cm(cls):
        pass

    @synchronized # lock bound to function_sm
    @staticmethod
    def function_sm():
        pass
```

For more fine grained locking within methods of a class, you can also use it like a context manager:

```
class Class(object):

    @synchronized
    def function_im_1(self):
        pass

    def function_im_2(self):
        with synchronized(self):
            pass
```

and:

```
class Class(object):

    @synchronized
    @classmethod
    def function_cm(cls):
        pass

    def function_im(self):
        with synchronized(Class):
            pass
```

Comment: Very handy. This should be submitted as a PEP!

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of **class function** is not very clearly to me. So I shows two different locks, one for **class methods**, another one for **instance methods**, in the following code.

And we need to use `try...finally` around the calling of `func` inside the decorator

```
def synchronized(func):
    """ Assumes that the first parameter of func has `_lock` property
    """
    def wrapper(owner, *args, **kwargs):
        owner._lock.acquire()
        try:
            return func(owner, *args, **kwargs)
        finally:
            owner._lock.release()
    return wrapper


class Something(object):
    _lock = Lock()  # for class methods

    def __init__(self):
        self._lock = Lock()  # for instance methods

    @synchronized
    def instance_method(self):
        print 'instance method invoked...'

    @classmethod
    @synchronized
    def class_method(cls):
        print 'class method invoked...'
```